# how can i get rid of extra space in explode statement

Tags: php

PHP Code

```
  $testcases1 = explode(" ",$_POST['testcases']);
  $num1 = $testcases1[0];
  $num2 = $testcases1[1];
  echo "count-"count($testcases1);
  echo "num2-"$num2;
```

**Correct**

```
     i/p : 3 2 
     o/p : count-2
           num2-2
```

**My Issue**

```
     i/p : 3(just a single space)
     o/p : count-2 
           num2-
```

and $num2 is behaving as it has the value 0  what can i do for this ...

num2 can be 0 to 100... how do i acheive this

Comment: why not you use trim function

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rtrim()` to remove the spaces http://php.net/rtrim

```
$testcases1 = explode(" ",$_POST['testcases']);
$num1 = rtrim($testcases1[0], ' ');
$num2 = rtrim($testcases1[1], ' ');
echo "count-"count($testcases1);
echo "num2-"$num2;
```

If multiple spaces between the 2 numbers

```
$testcases1 = array_keys(array_filter(explode(' ', $_POST['testcases'])));
$num1 = rtrim($testcases1[0], ' ');
$num2 = rtrim($testcases1[1], ' ');
echo "count-"count($testcases1);
echo "num2-"$num2;
```

Comment: i cant use trim to an array  - trim works only for strings,,,(trim() expects parameter 1 to be string)

Comment: @jane you're right, i missed that. Could you please provide a sample of what `$_POST['testcases']` returns?

Comment: 3 2        hence      $num1=3     $num2=2

Comment: @jane i am not getting any errors with the code. `$num1 = rtrim($testcases1[0], ' ');`  and `$num2 = rtrim($testcases1[1], ' ');` both are strings `var_dump($testcases1[0]); var_dump($testcases1[1]);` returns `string(1) "3" string(1) "2"`

Comment: @jane does `$_POST['testcases']` have 2 spaces between the numbers? Try this, replace `$testcases1 = explode(" ",$_POST['testcases']);` with `$testcases1 = array_keys(array_filter(explode(' ', $_POST['testcases'])));`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that your `$_POST['testcases']` contain a trailing white space.

You should trim `$_POST['testcases']`, so that it explodes correctly. Alter your first line to:

```
$testcases1 = explode(" ",trim($_POST['testcases']));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that there is more than 1 space between the numbers and that causes spaces to become part of your result array.

In that case you are better off using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) as that can split on a regular expression:

```
$testcases1 = preg_split('/\s+/',$_POST['testcases']);
```

This will explode the string on 1 or more white-space characters (`\s`): Spaces, tabs or new-lines.

If you just want to explode on 1 or more spaces (no tabs or new-lines), you can use:

```
$testcases1 = preg_split('/[ ]+/',$_POST['testcases']);
```

On the other hand, if you need 2 inputs, you are probably better off using 2 input fields as that will avoid these kinds of parsing problems.